# Sort a list of objects based on an integer of the object field c#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a list of joints

```
List<Joint> joints = new();
```

The `Joint` class looks like this:

```
class Joint
{
    private Node node1, node2;
    private int weight;

    public Joint(Node node1, Node node2)
    {
        this.node1 = node1;
        this.node2 = node2;
        weight = GetWeight();
    }
        
    private int GetWeight()
    {
        return (int)Math.Sqrt
                ((int)Math.Pow(node1.GetX() - node2.GetX(), 2) + 
                (int)Math.Pow(node1.GetY() - node2.GetY(), 2));
    }
}
```

I would like to sort the joints list based on the weight value it contains. Preferably in only a few lines

Comment: All of your properties and methods are private. How do you want to sort based on them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort `List<i>` in place, all you need is [Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-8.0) method:

```
joints.Sort((a, b) => a.GetWeight().CompareTo(b.GetWeight()));
```

Note, that you may want to make `GetWeight` method being `public`. An alternative is to make `Joint` being [comparable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=net-8.0):

```
public class Joint: IComparable<Joint> {
  ...
  public int CompareTo(Joint other) {
    if (other == null)
      return 1;

    return GetWeight().CompareTo(other.GetWeight());
  }
}
```

if `Joint` is comparable, you can put just

```
joints.Sort();
```

Comment: `GetWeight` is private in the OP code

Comment: @Jamiec -- that is because it is never polite to ask an object their weight :)

Comment: Women, yes. Joints are happy to disclose their weight.

Comment: @Jamiec -- not this Joint apparently.  Maybe it is shy.

Comment: Why use sort over, orderby?

Comment: @johnny 5: `OrderBy` creates overhead, `joints = joints.OrderBy(item => item.GetWeight()).ToList();` makes a new list. `OrderBy` is OK if we want two list: unsorted original and sorted one.